# Add UIButton to UITableViewCell in case search has no results, empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I got the following code to show a `button` on first `UITableViewCell`in case the `NSArray` with the search results is empty. Now, my `numberOfRowsInSection` has `NSArray` + 1, this way, my table will always have, at least, one cell.

This is in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]) {
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if ((self.searchDisplayController.isActive && indexPath.row == [self.searchResults count]) || (!self.searchDisplayController.isActive && indexPath.row == [[self pegarObjetosUnicos] count])) {

        // Create UIButton
        UIButton *botaoProcurar = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        botaoProcurar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
        botaoProcurar.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
        [botaoProcurar setTitle:@"Procurar no Banco de Dados" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        botaoProcurar.tag = 1;
        [botaoProcurar addTarget:self action:@selector(botaoProcurar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:botaoProcurar];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
        return cell;
    }
```

The code first removes a `subview`, in case it finds one, and then create and add the `button` as `subview`in case the search `array` is empty.

It works perfectly, I don't have any problems with this code, but since I need to do something similar now, I'm just wondering if this is the best approach. I'm just not comfortable with running this code for every cell my tableview has to render. I thought about adding the button to the `NSArray` when the database connection returned empty, but still, it wouldn't be a nice code.

Any suggestions for a more objective and clean code would be great. If not, a "Go for it! you are doing fine", will work as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the button in the header or footer of the tableview. If the array has results, Remove the footer or header of the tableview. If the array has no results add the view to the footer or header. You should place this code in your function that decides if the array has data or not. This way the placement of the UIBUtton is not cell dependent, so now you won't have to run it for each and every cell you will have in the tableview.